# using datepicker on mvc doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I would like to use the datepicker, i saw this simple page

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

i downloaded these tow jquery files

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js  and put it in `GoogleDatePicker1.js`

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js and put it in `GoogleDatePicker2.js`

and i dowloaded this css file

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css and put it in `datePickerCSS.css`

and i added these files to my project like this

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/functions.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/GoogleDatePicker1.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/GoogleDatePicker2.js")
}

@Styles.Render("~/css/datePickerCSS.css")
```

the `functions.js` is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").click(function () {
        datepicker();
    });
});
```

and my html is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.startDate, new { placeholder = "mm/dd/yyyy", @class = "datepicker" })
```

but when i click on this textbox, google chrome tells me that the datepicker is not defined.

#### i make an alert before the datepicker() function and it is working

any help?()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the datepicker to the element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: i already tried that before posint this question and i got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: datepicker is not defined `

Comment: Can you confirm via devtools or firebug the javascript file is being included?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you define the function `datepicker()` that you're trying to call?

It looks like you're using the plugin incorrectly.  Consider [the example in the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

What you're trying to do is *initialize* the date picker when you click on it.  This is incorrect.  You should initialize it when the page loads, then the plugin itself will handle the click event.  Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: i already tried that before posting the question but i still get the exception `Uncaught ReferenceError: datepicker is not defined `,

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});
```